# Math error 1e18 - 0.1e18, is there a problem?

Tags: solidity, math

When I run this code, the output is `1e16` or `10000000000000000`, shouldn't it be `0.9e18` or `9e17`?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract A {
    function addthis() public pure returns(uint256) {
     
        uint256 fromSharesAfter = 1e18;
        uint256 lmao = 0.1e18;
        uint c = fromSharesAfter - lmao;
        return  c;
    }
}
```

Comment: which environment are you running this? Because it worked fine in remix.

Comment: Shanghai, but yea somehow it works again. Well I guess this is coding life :")

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing is when I add some other variable compiled it, then undo the changes so as compile again, remix, output the correct variable `9e17` or `0.9e18`

Answer (score 0):

Just don't try to use floating point arithmetic or decimal numbers. Solidity doesn't really support these.

0.1e18 = 1e17